# Create New HTML Page With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a new html document using javascript, with a specified name and save it in the same folder as the parent page.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Even if you open the page directly from the file system (e.g., double-click it in a file explorer or similar), there's no standard mechanism for allowing script to write files to the file system. If you're loading the page from a server, of course the script in the page can't *directly* write files on that server.

The standard way to approach this is to have a server-side resource that the page can send the file contents to, which does any necessary security checks and then saves the file to the server.

Comment: Firstly, Thanks for your reply! Secondly, How would I go about writing this program to read, scan and save the file? Would I have to use a language like php, or could I do it with Javascript?

Comment: @jacquesca: You can use any of dozens of server-side environments. PHP is a common option, as are JavaScript (via NodeJS, SilkJS, DecafJS), the various .Net languages (C#, VB, JScript -- that last being very JavaScript-like), Perl, Python, Java...

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about JavaScript running in a web browser, this is not possible as JavaScript is executed in a sandbox and you don't have access to the file system.

Answer (score 0):

you can't create a page directly with javascript. recall that js runs on the client and what you are trying to do is saving a page in server. what you can do is, you can makeup the html code in client side and send it to server, where a script running there will save the page.